# Shortcode execution inside of a simple field (custom field)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need your help as I mentioned in title that I want to use shot codes inside of the Simple text field as a custom field (Belongs to Simple fields WordPress Plugin )As of now its not executing to

`[caption]Testing[/caption]`..while I have made captions returns in the the HTML format..

Any solution would be highly Appreciated ..here is the the HTML I want to use using Shortcodes ..

```
<div class="box_wrap clearfix">
  <div clas="heading">
    Call to Action
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    &nbsp;  
  </div>
</div>
```

Le me know how can I execute this HTML by making shortcode of this inside a Custom text filed!1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> When the_content is displayed, the shortcode API will parse any
>   registered shortcodes such as "[myshortcode]", separate and parse the
>   attributes and content, if any, and pass them the corresponding
>   shortcode handler function. Any string returned (not echoed) by the
>   shortcode handler will be inserted into the post body in place of the
>   shortcode itself.

In otherwords you need to apply **the_content** filter where you output your content in your template.

So instead of having code like this:

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your_meta_key', true );
```

Use this instead:

```
// Get your custom meta data using get_post_meta() function
$meta_content = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your_meta_key', true );

// Then we need to apply 'the_content' filter on the $meta_content
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $meta_content );
```

And your shortcode should be taken into account. IF you have registered the shortcode that is...

**Read more about:** 
- [Shortcode API here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).
- [the_content filter here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).
- [apply_filters() function here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters)